# Running local server for Rails 2.3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I am trying to run a Rails 2.3 app locally.

`script/server` gives me these errors:

```
bash: script/server: Permission denied
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
```

`script/server` gives me the error:

```
/Users/stevenbrooks1111/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- initializer (LoadError)
from /Users/stevenbrooks1111/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/stevenbrooks1111/Desktop/cssmixonline/cssweb/config/boot.rb:55:in `load_initializer'
from /Users/stevenbrooks1111/Desktop/cssmixonline/cssweb/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
from /Users/stevenbrooks1111/Desktop/cssmixonline/cssweb/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
from /Users/stevenbrooks1111/Desktop/cssmixonline/cssweb/config/boot.rb:110:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/stevenbrooks1111/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/stevenbrooks1111/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from script/server:2:in `<main>'
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
```

Any ideas of how I can get this to run locally?

Comment: Why you using rails 2.3

Comment: This is related to, and a partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291048/rails-2-3-4-errors-rails-s-bundle-not-working

Comment: This is a friends applications from 2008 that is why it is in rails 2.3

Answer (score 1):

This question is what I've been doing for the past month. I would have loved to use Rails 4, but I know better than to try it!

Install rvm or rbenv, then get into a server that correctly runs this app, and run

```
ruby --version
gem list > ~/myGems.txt
```

Using rvm or rbenv, install the exact same version of Ruby.

(Tip: whenever I say "exact same", you can fudge by bumping the revision. For example, given a gem with version 0.1.4, if it has subsequent versions 0.1.5, 0.1.6, and 0.2.0, you can bump to 0.1.6, if that will save you some grief. The revision numbers, 0.1.*, are supposed to be only bug fixes. But a minor version bump, 0.2.0, has higher odds of breaking things. I kept the same version of Ruby, but I bumped rails to 2.3.14.)

Using rvm or rbenv, install the *same* version of Ruby as currently runs on this app's main server.

Inside this Ruby environment (with both `which ruby` and `ruby --version` reporting the correct answers), install each gem in myGems.txt, like this:

```
gem install --ignore-dependencies --no-rdoc --no-ri my_gem -v=0.1.4
```

The --ignore-dependencies is critical, because some gems from the Pleistocene Epoch, 2009, don't specify their dependencies' versions. When some dumb 2009 gem pulls in the 2013 `rake`, you will be utterly screwed, because reverting that rake is really hard. And don't forget to set the -v to the same value as myGems.txt reports!

After all that, try simple `rake` commands like `rake routes`. Post any bugs you get as fresh questions, but remember to point out Rails 2.3 in the subject so nobody mis-answers with the modern fixes.

And if this app has tests or specs, getting them running should be a top priority, so you can resume TDD, leaning on the tests to allow you to make sick changes.